# Can I get the diff data for one file between two commits via the GH API?

Tags: ruby, github, github-api, octokit

I know how to get the commit for a file via the API, along with the SHA and all that nice stuff.

But, suppose I just want the diff of a file in 1 commit or the diff of the same file across two commits.

For instance, in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ea759cb76161a7a0003c3cd3b38a8a125a99af3c#diff-a215bfc911ab0913d92695a0f20310ef), say I wanted just the `, :counter_sql` in the `activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb`.

How do I get at that diff data via the API?

I am using Octokit.rb.

**Edit 1**

It seems that this is possible [per this blog post](https://developer.github.com/changes/2012-12-10-Diff-and-patch-media-types/), but I am just not sure how to do it with Octokit.

**Edit 2**

So, I am kinda figuring it out little by little.

To get the diff data between two commits, I can compare [two commits like this](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits).

So, assuming I have the two SHAs for both commits in two variables `a` and `b`, I would do something like this:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: ENV["MY_ACCESS_TOKEN"])
comparison = client.compare("rails/rails", a, b, path: "activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb")
```

This issue is that this results in a diff between both commits, which includes changes to many other files and a lot of information I don't want.

All I want is the diff from this specific file across these two commits.

I haven't figured out how to do that yet.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible.

You can use the Compare API to get the diff between two commits, which will include all files, not just the file you're interested in, as you observed. So you'd need to do some filtering on your end.

Another approach might be to get the contents of the file at commit X and then at commit Y, and then compute the diff between those two versions of files on your end (there's no GitHub API for diffing in general). You can use to Contents API to fetch the raw versions of files.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents

Comment: Anyway I take it, I will have to do filtering it seems, because to get at the file I want, I have to filter for it (per the commits). Or are you suggesting that I can get all the commits for a specific file and just diff two versions of that file on the same commit?

Comment: @marcamillion I concur with Ivan Zuzak that to get a diff of a single file between two commits you better use the GH Contents API and generate the diff inside your application.

Comment: @marcamillion You can fetch the version of a file at a specific commit. So, if you want to get a diff for a specific file between two commits (X and Y), you need to fetch the version of the file at commit X (API request 1) and then the version at commit Y (API request 2), and then diff the two versions locally on your end. No filtering required here, you just need to do the diff on your end. If you compare the two approaches suggested, in one you need to filter some data you don't need and in the other you need to compute the diff on your end. Filtering is easier than computing the diff

Comment: @IvanZuzak I like where your head is at, and I found a gem that may actually do the computation of the diff for me - https://github.com/samg/diffy So I am inclined to agree with your suggestion, but disagree with your conclusion (that filtering is easier). So I guess my follow-up question is, how do I actually get the version of the file within commit X? I tried doing `client.commits(repo, ref: commits2.first.sha, path: path)` and that still returns the entire commit, not the specific version for just the file I want. I also tried `sha:` in the `commits()` method but no dice.

Comment: @IvanZuzak Actually nevermind, I forgot I solved this in another SO question, by simply using `contents` like this: `c1 = client.contents(repo, path: path, ref: commits2.first.sha)`.