# Why is the 'content' for two separate commits identical from the GH API?

Tags: ruby, git, github, github-api, octokit

I have two commits. [This one](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c6e01f5b60c4864f0e92149d1e81077519f503d5) and [this one](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/581f12b7b18a6e5205bfabb814f6e9997bf92be8). I am using Octokit.

I am primarily interested in the diffs related to the file `activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb` in both commits.

I have both of these commits in a collection as you can see here:

```
[284] pry(main)> commits2.first.sha
=> "c6e01f5b60c4864f0e92149d1e81077519f503d5"
[285] pry(main)> commits2.second.sha
=> "581f12b7b18a6e5205bfabb814f6e9997bf92be8"
```

Note both of those SHAs correspond to the SHAs in the links I posted above, and both are unique (i.e. different than each other).

Yet, when I get the content for each of those commits, specifically related to the path I am interested in, I get the same result for both commits.

```
pry(main)> repo
=> "rails/rails"
pry(main)> path
=> "activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb"
c1 = client.contents(repo, path: path, sha: commits2.first.sha)
pry(main)> c1.sha
=> "3729e22e6423348aa9282cd17b49c09793ca3a6f"
```

Then I do the same thing for the second commit, I get the following:

```
pry(main)> c2 = client.contents(repo, path: path, sha: commits2.second.sha)
pry(main)> c2.sha
=> "3729e22e6423348aa9282cd17b49c09793ca3a6f"
```

Note the SHAs are identical.

The content for both `c1` and `c2` are also identical. You can see them below:

```
pry(main)> c1
=> {:name=>"associations.rb",
 :path=>"activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb",
 :sha=>"3729e22e6423348aa9282cd17b49c09793ca3a6f",
 :size=>94931,
 :url=>
  "https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/contents/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb?ref=master",
 :html_url=>
  "https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb",
 :git_url=>
  "https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/git/blobs/3729e22e6423348aa9282cd17b49c09793ca3a6f",
 :download_url=>
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rails/rails/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb",
 :type=>"file",
 :content=>
  "cmVxdWlyZSAnYWN0aXZlX3N1cHBvcnQvY29yZV9leHQvZW51bWVyYWJsZScK\ncmVxdWlyZSAnYWN0aXZlX3N1cHBvcnQvY29yZV9leHQvc3RyaW5nL2NvbnZl\ncnNpb25zJwpyZXF1aXJlICdhY3RpdmVfc3VwcG9ydC9jb3JlX2V4dC9tb2R1\nbGUvcmVtb3ZlX21ldGhvZCcKcmVxdWlyZSAnYWN0aXZlX3JlY29yZC9lcnJv\ncnMnCgptb2R1bGUgQWN0aXZlUmVjb3JkCiAgY2xhc3MgQXNzb2NpYXRpb25O\nb3RGb3VuZEVycm9yIDwgQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbkVycm9yICM6bm9kb2M6CiAg\nICBkZWYgaW5pdGlhbGl6ZShyZWNvcmQgPSBua
```

I truncated the `content` for Brevity.

Why does this happen? If you manually look at the both links I posted at the top, and scroll down to the `associations.rb` code, you will see that both have changes to that file.

So why would the `content` for BOTH commits be identical?

So confused :|

**Edit 1**

In response to Tim's comment that maybe the commits were cherry picked and they are indeed identical, I have done two more commits ([this one](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1d2c6ee8f3f7e4b6881f30e6b53582738c2b3ace) & [this one](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3c01e01ded4e8e87d48e844881c88f6e47cebdf0)), yet the result seems to be the same:

```
[299] pry(main)> commits2.third.html_url
=> "https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1d2c6ee8f3f7e4b6881f30e6b53582738c2b3ace"
[300] pry(main)> commits2.third.sha
=> "1d2c6ee8f3f7e4b6881f30e6b53582738c2b3ace"
[301] pry(main)> commits2.fourth.html_url
=> "https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3c01e01ded4e8e87d48e844881c88f6e47cebdf0"
[302] pry(main)> commits2.fourth.sha
=> "3c01e01ded4e8e87d48e844881c88f6e47cebdf0"

pry(main)> c3 = client.contents(repo, path: path, sha: commits2.third.sha)
pry(main)> c3.sha
=> "3729e22e6423348aa9282cd17b49c09793ca3a6f"

pry(main)> c4 = client.contents(repo, path: path, sha: commits2.fourth.sha)
 pry(main)> c4.sha
=> "3729e22e6423348aa9282cd17b49c09793ca3a6f"
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Octokit, but perhaps you have two branches which are pointing to the same commit?  Alternatively, maybe a commit was cherry picked, and so you seem (almost) identical content on two branches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It would seem like they are identical, but that's why I included the links initially to prove that they aren't. In either case, I just redid the same exercise with another 2 commits to illustrate the point. Refresh the question to see.

Comment: This is almost certainly a lack in our understanding of Oktokit, rather than, for example, Git happening to create two commits with the same SHA-1 hash, which is less likely than the Earth spiraling into the sun.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am pretty sure of that too...hence why I am here :)

Comment: I don't know Octokit at all and have not used GitHub at this level, but looking at https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/ suggests that this particular GitHub API does not allow arbitrary SHA-1 hashes.  If that is the case, presumably Octokit is completely ignoring your `sha:` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GitHub API Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) suggests that you must refer to the desired commit/branch/tag with the `ref` option, whereas you are using `sha`.

Therefore the correct code will be this:

```
c1 = client.contents(repo, path: path, ref: commits2.first.sha)
c2 = client.contents(repo, path: path, ref: commits2.second.sha)
```

Comment: ZOMG dude....MONEY! Thanks much. You are absolutely right. That was it. A simple fix. Thanks much!

Comment: Any chance you may be able to chime in on this one too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417195/can-i-get-the-diff-data-for-one-file-between-two-commits-via-the-gh-api